# How to deal with "this" context with functions used in event listeners?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I construct that applies click and key press event listeners to specified elements on a page.

The events fire a function that uses data stored in the object.

I need to be able to use the "this" keyword (surely?) but due to how the functions are called the "this" keyword points towards the window object.

To solve this problem I have "handlers" saved in my object that reference the functions and also apply .bind(this) to them.

```
this.handlers = {
        inputMouseMoveHandler: this.inputMouseMove.bind( this ),
        inputDownHandler: this.inputDown.bind( this ),
        inputUpHandler: this.inputUp.bind( this )
    }
```

and then I can use remove and add event listeners on them while keeping the context of this pointing towards my object.

```
document.addEventListener( "mousemove", this.handlers.inputMouseMoveHandler );
document.addEventListener( "keydown", this.handlers.inputDownHandler );
document.addEventListener( "keyup", this.handlers.inputUpHandler );
```

and

```
document.removeEventListener( "mousemove", this.handlers.inputMouseMoveHandler );
document.removeEventListener( "keydown", this.handlers.inputDownHandler );
document.removeEventListener( "keyup", this.handlers.inputUpHandler );
```

Essentially I'm wondering if this is the correct way to do things?

Comment: It's as good a solution as any other, particularly if you have a need to remove those specific handlers later.

Comment: Id say so.  Its quite common to assign this to a variable so that it can be accessed from sub-functions.  It's really the only way around the fact that every function has its own this.

Comment: @Ryhnn that's contradictory - the latter is also a good approach, but it's not the one you agreed with in the first few words ;-).  As it happens in jQuery-based code I prefer that latter approach because it preserves the jQuery semantic that `this` refers to the element receiving the event and not the enclosing object.

Comment: What benefit would the method I'm currently using have over `var mythis = this;` and then using `mythis.inputMouseMove` and not having to store handlers to be able to correctly remove them later? [edit: underscore wasn't showing]